# hamburger menu with image slider

Tags: javascript, html, css

I create Navarro with the carousel image slider but when i click to the hamburger the image do not disappear, I do not why. I put the code in the demo can you please see and you can understand what I mean and if you can help me to solve this problems. Thank you

```js
const hamburger = document.querySelector(".hamburger");
const navLinks = document.querySelector(".nav-links");
const links = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-links li");
hamburger.addEventListener("click", () => {
  navLinks.classList.toggle("open");
  links.forEach(link => {
    link.classList.toggle("fade");
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

nav {
  height: 10vh;
  background: #5b78c7;
}

.nav-links {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.nav-links li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.landing {
  height: 90vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.landing h1 {
  margin: 100px;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #ae5fce;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .line {
    width: 30px;
    height: 3px;
    background: white;
    margin: 5px;
  }
  nav {
    position: relative;
  }
  .hamburger {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    right: 5%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-5%, -50%);
    z-index: 2;
  }
  .nav-links {
    position: fixed;
    background: #5b78c7;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
    clip-path: circle(100px at 90% -10%);
    -webkit-clip-path: circle(100px at 90% -10%);
    transition: all 1s ease-out;
    pointer-events: none;
  }
  .nav-links.open {
    clip-path: circle(1000px at 90% -10%);
    -webkit-clip-path: circle(1000px at 90% -10%);
    pointer-events: all;
  }
  .landing {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .nav-links li {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .nav-links li a {
    font-size: 25px;
  }
  .nav-links li:nth-child(1) {
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0.2s;
  }
  .nav-links li:nth-child(2) {
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0.4s;
  }
  .nav-links li:nth-child(3) {
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0.6s;
  }
  li.fade {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav>
  <div class="hamburger">
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="line"></div>
  </div>
  <ul class="nav-links">
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<section class="landing">
  <img src="./circles.svg" alt="dots" />
  <h1>Dots</h1>
  <div class="container-fluid px-0">
    <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner bg-info" role="listbox">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center min-vh-100">
            <h1 class="display-1">ONE</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center min-vh-100">
            <h1 class="display-1">TWO</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center min-vh-100">
            <h1 class="display-1">THREE</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: You need to change z-index on your .nav class

Comment: Thank you for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply z-index update following css `z-index: 1;`.

```
.nav-links {
    position: fixed;
    background: #5b78c7;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
    clip-path: circle(100px at 90% -10%);
    -webkit-clip-path: circle(100px at 90% -10%);
    transition: all 1s ease-out;
    pointer-events: none;
    z-index: 1;
}
```